# PHP function for GREP or FINDSTR

Tags: php, grep, findstr

Is there any predefined function in PHP or any other scripting language that performs the same function that GREP or FINDSTR performs in console. 
I want to perform the following code in scripting language;

```
findstr /i/g:finddata.txt /f:filelist.txt > results.txt
```

here, finddata.txt is the file containing the words to be matched, filelist.txt contains the list of files from where the words be matched and result.txt prints the output.

I wanted to match few words stored in a file to another file and print all the sentences that contains the matched words in another file. if it could highlight the matched words (color/italics/bold etc.) it will be be much appreciated.

Comment: No, there's no built-in function in php that does that.

Comment: Thanks Federico!

Comment: While there isn't a built-in function in PHP, grep already exists as a command that you can use in the shell scripting language, so it's not clear what you're looking for here

Comment: There isn't a single built in function in PHP which will replicate the behavious of the command - because PHP is a programming language. It provides the primitives which you assemble in order to recreate the desired functionality - be that finding words, running a social network, a blog, guidance system for ICBMs....